# Delete and get by ID Angular.js and Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, servlets

I'm building a simple Angular.js, Java HttpServlet, MongoDB  web project. Unfortunately, since I am new to Angular and HttpServlet, I have a few issues. The GET (the get all version) and POST methods work fine all the way, inserting and retrieving from Mongo through the Java service to the Angular UI.

However, DELETE returns a 405 method not allowed error, despite me updating tomcat's xml file to allow the operations as per other answers on this site. I then attempted to make a GET method to allow retrieval of a single category by ID, but this fails with a 404 error despite being nearly identical to existing code.

Questions:

Do I need to POST to urls like /angular/1 or is POST ok as /angular, since it is working?

Does the failing getByID method keep DELETE from working, or if not, what is the issue?

and finally: Why does the getByID method encounter a 404?

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX with Servlets using AngularJS</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller("MyController", MyController);

function MyController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : '/Service4/angular'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.category = data;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                });

        };
        
        $scope.deleteCategory = function() {
            $http({
                method : 'DELETE',
                url : '/Service4/angular',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: 'id='+ $scope.deleteCat
                
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //display data, removed for brevity
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });    

        };
    
    $scope.postDataToServer = function() {
        $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/Service4/angular',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: 'name='+ $scope.name
                
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/Service4/angular'
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.category = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    };
    
    $scope.getCatByID = function(getID) {
        $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/Service4/angular/' + $scope.getID
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.category = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    };
        
};


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <button ng-click="getDataFromServer()">Fetch data from
                server</button>

            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="c in category">
                    <td>{{c._id}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <form ng-submit="postDataToServer()">
                <input ng-model="name" type="text" name="name" />
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>

            <form ng-submit="deleteCategory()">
                <input ng-model="delete" type="text" name="deleteCat" />
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>

            <form ng-submit="getCatByID()">
                <input ng-model="getID" type="text" name="getID" />
                <button type="submit">Get by ID</button>
            </form>
            

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/angular")
public class AngularServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idCount = 0;
    private DB db;
    private MongoClient mongo;
    private DBCollection col; 
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AngularServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@GET
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,

HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    //mongo cursor creation removed for brevity
    List<DBObject> all2 = cursor.toArray();

    String json = new Gson().toJson(all2);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);

    out.close();
}

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
protected void getCategoryByID(HttpServletRequest request,

HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("id") String id) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //mongo manipulation removed for brevity
    List<DBObject> all2 = cursor.toArray();

    String json = new Gson().toJson(all2);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);

    out.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@DELETE
protected void doDELETE(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

        String id = "";
        id = request.getParameter("id");

        Category cat = new Category();
        cat.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("_id", cat.getId()).get();
        WriteResult result = col.remove(query);

    }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@POST
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

        String name = "";

        name = request.getParameter("name");

        //removed for brevity

    }

private static DBObject createDBObject(Category cat) {
    //removed for brevity
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my @Path annotations are being completely ignored. I don't know why yet, but I think a different question is appropriate.